# Can mountebank be used to mock a GET octet-stream image file using stub and predicate?

Tags: mountebank

When using a text file, this works like a regular GET

```
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "is": {
        "headers": {
          "content-disposition": "attachment; filename=sample_text_file.txt"
        },
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body":  "<%- stringify(filename, 'templates/attachments/sample_text_file.txt') %>"
      }
    }
  ],
  "predicates": [
    {
      "and": [
        {
          "equals": {
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/resources/4df3dab6-003b-440d"
          }
        }            
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when an image file is used in place of text file, the Mountebank fails to start.